# Network Diagram Generator

Tags: networking, active-directory

Does anyone know if a `network diagram generator` exists?

Tool for get information such as: how many networks you have, the ip addresses, subnet masks, sites, servers, network drives shared, and so on then it will generate a diagram.

I have seen **Active Directory Topology Diagrammer** tool

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13380#Instructions

> The Microsoft Active Directory Topology Diagrammer reads an Active
>   Directory configuration using LDAP, and then automatically generates a
>   Visio diagram of your Active Directory and /or your Exchange Server
>   topology. The diagramms may include domains, sites, servers,
>   organizational units, DFS-R, administrative groups, routing groups and
>   connectors and can be changed manually in Visio if needed.
>
> Microsoft.com, Downloads page, Brief Description

https://www.petri.com/using-active-directory-topology-diagrammer

I'm NOT administrator Active Directory, only user.

Any suggestions about it?

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest giving [MJL85](https://github.com/MJL85/mnet) a try.

Pre-requisites:

- [Python](https://www.python.org/)
- [Graphviz](http://graphviz.org/) dot tool

It is a set of python scripts that can analyse and diagram networks with the Graphviz dot tool producing the graphical output.

### Example Graph

From the authors site:
[image]

The tool is:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Should run on multiple platforms.

Comment: @Kiquenet did you try this? Did it work for you? if so, please accept as answer, to help others in future.  Steve, that looks great, thanks (+1). You might also want to answer [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/43084/network-documentation-software/48251)