# Network documentation software

Tags: windows, networking, network-monitor, network-administration, network-scanner

I am looking for a product to allow me to perform network documentation, with the hopes of expanding on it to discover network-connected devices (and count based on type).

Presently I am looking for a Windows Solution, but am open to other platforms should there be adequate documentation. The only other **preferences** are that it be OpenSource, or to cost me approximately $50.00.

The following is the type of document I wish to generate:

[image: Main Menu Image]

---

The following is the summary of the device types:
[image]

Comment: how do you wish to generate the diagram? Will you manually input it? Do you seek some s/w which will scan your network & generate the diagram?

Answer (score 1):

The following list of tools are capable of performing the function you desire. My **personal recommendation** for use would be the SpiceWorks option.

---

**Solarwinds Network Topology Mapper**

The following is provided from the programs' official [webpage](https://www.solarwinds.com/network-topology-mapper):

> Key Features:
>
> 1. Automate device discovery and mapping Build multiple maps from a single scan
> 2. Export network diagrams to Visio Auto-detect changes to network topology
> 3. Perform multi-level network discovery Address regulatory PCI compliance

Note you will be limited to a trial as the full product cost $1,000.00+

**Microsoft Visio**

The price for Microsoft Visio varies depending on version, licensing and location. This product is capable of manually allowing you to make network diagrams.

Other notable mentions of software are:

1. [10-strike network diagram](https://www.10-strike.com/network-diagram/)
2. [lanflow](http://www.pacestar.com/lanflow/index.html)
3. [Graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org/)
4. [Spiceworks](https://www.spiceworks.com/)

Comment: Dude (literally, your handle @Dude), I am going to edit your answer to be a little more informative (links, blurbs etc.) with the hope we can mark it as an upvote! Remember, the more information you post, the better quality the answer shall be.

Comment: I've gone and edited your answer (pending peer review). Although I must mention you've not stated *why* you prefer Spiceworks, and how it meets the OP's requirements.

Comment: Please do not post lists of dozens of software. If you post links to 5 tools, I like 1 of them and dislike 4, I cannot give you 3 downvotes, but certainly one. Instead, please post 5 separate answers, if they are really a fit. Then I can vote on each one individually. Be aware that you describe how each one meets the requirements.

Comment: "Thanks a lot for help me" @Network_infrastructure welcome onboard. We say "thank you" by upvoting. And, if you get an answer that works for you, please accept it which will help others who read the question in future.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [the Dude](https://mikrotik.com/thedude) :-)

> Some of it's features
>
> - Auto network discovery and layout
> - Discovers any type or brand of device
> - Device, Link monitoring, and notifications
> - Includes SVG icons for devices, and supports custom icons and backgrounds
> - Easy installation and usage
> - Allows you to draw your own maps and add custom devices
> - Supports SNMP, ICMP, DNS and TCP monitoring for devices that support it
> - Individual Link usage monitoring and graphs
> - Direct access to remote control tools for device management
> - Supports remote Dude server and local client
> - Runs in Linux Wine environment, MacOS Darwine, and Windows

Unfortunately, I have not used it in years, and it has now become commercial, whereas it was free before.

You can [enquire about the price](https://mikrotik.com/buy) or get the last free version from [here](http://www.download82.com/download/windows/the-dude/).

***Wait***, that "last free version" is the same as the current download version, so I am not clear what it happening - maybe it's one of those which is free to use, but you can pay for support?

[image]

Comment: "prefect". Not sure if word play, or misspelled perfect.

Comment: The prices (I believe) are for infrastructure/cloud operating instances.

Comment: Ok, ok!! So my spelling is not prefect :-)   Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Just checked the software, The Dude is actually a client, and you need to provide to it a server IP. The server is an installation of RouterOS, which is only free to try (https://mikrotik.com/software)